# how do i use NPOI in Unity，InvalidOperationException error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, npoi

I want to export a .docx file by NPOI in Unity.But it gave me an error.The same code can work in FormsApp，but it can not work in Unity.

```
FileStream stream = File.Open(sPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(stream);
stream.Close();
FileStream newStream = new FileStream(tPath, FileMode.Create);
doc.Write(newStream); // ERROR LINE
newStream.Close();
```

> InvalidOperationException: Type NPOI.OpenXmlFormats.ItemChoiceType is
>   missing enumeration value 'vstream' for element 'vstream from
>   namespace
>   'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/docPropsVTypes'.
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportElementInfo
>   (System.Type cls, System.String defaultName, System.String
>   defaultNamespace, System.Type defaultType,
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeMapMemberElement member,
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributes atts)
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.CreateMapMember
>   (System.Type declaringType,
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionMember rmember, System.String
>   defaultNamespace)
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportClassMapping
>   (System.Xml.Serialization.TypeData typeData,
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute root, System.String
>   defaultNamespace) Rethrow as InvalidOperationException: There was an
>   error reflecting field 'Item'.
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportClassMapping
>   (System.Xml.Serialization.TypeData typeData,
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute root, System.String
>   defaultNamespace)
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping
>   (System.Xml.Serialization.TypeData typeData,
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute root, System.String
>   defaultNamespace) Rethrow as InvalidOperationException: There was an
>   error reflecting type 'NPOI.OpenXmlFormats.CT_Property'.
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping
>   (System.Xml.Serialization.TypeData typeData,
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute root, System.String
>   defaultNamespace)
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping
>   (System.Type type, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute root,
>   System.String defaultNamespace)
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportElementInfo
>   (System.Type cls, System.String defaultName, System.String
>   defaultNamespace, System.Type defaultType,
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeMapMemberElement member,
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributes atts)
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.CreateMapMember
>   (System.Type declaringType,
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionMember rmember, System.String
>   defaultNamespace)
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportClassMapping
>   (System.Xml.Serialization.TypeData typeData,
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute root, System.String
>   defaultNamespace) Rethrow as InvalidOperationException: There was an
>   error reflecting field 'property'.
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportClassMapping
>   (System.Xml.Serialization.TypeData typeData,
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute root, System.String
>   defaultNamespace)
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping
>   (System.Xml.Serialization.TypeData typeData,
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute root, System.String
>   defaultNamespace) Rethrow as InvalidOperationException: There was an
>   error reflecting type 'NPOI.OpenXmlFormats.CT_CustomProperties'.
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping
>   (System.Xml.Serialization.TypeData typeData,
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute root, System.String
>   defaultNamespace)
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping
>   (System.Type type, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute root,
>   System.String defaultNamespace)
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer..ctor (System.Type type,
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeOverrides overrides,
>   System.Type[] extraTypes, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute
>   root, System.String defaultNamespace)
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer..ctor (System.Type type)
>   NPOI.OpenXmlFormats.CustomPropertiesDocument..cctor () Rethrow as
>   TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type
>   initializer for NPOI.OpenXmlFormats.CustomPropertiesDocument
>   NPOI.POIXMLProperties..cctor () Rethrow as
>   TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type
>   initializer for NPOI.POIXMLProperties
>   NPOI.POIXMLDocument.GetProperties () Rethrow as POIXMLException
>   NPOI.POIXMLDocument.GetProperties () NPOI.POIXMLDocument.Write
>   (System.IO.Stream stream) UiControl.OutWord () (at
>   Assets/Script/UiControl.cs:312) UiControl.Grp1Btn2Click () (at
>   Assets/Script/UiControl.cs:288) EventDelegate.Execute () (at
>   Assets/NGUI/Scripts/Internal/EventDelegate.cs:476)
>   EventDelegate.Execute (System.Collections.Generic.List`1 list) (at
>   Assets/NGUI/Scripts/Internal/EventDelegate.cs:644) UIButton.OnClick ()
>   (at Assets/NGUI/Scripts/Interaction/UIButton.cs:252)
>   UnityEngine.GameObject:SendMessage(String, Object, SendMessageOptions)
>   UICamera:Notify(GameObject, String, Object) (at
>   Assets/NGUI/Scripts/UI/UICamera.cs:1469)
>   UICamera:ProcessRelease(Boolean, Single) (at
>   Assets/NGUI/Scripts/UI/UICamera.cs:2325)
>   UICamera:ProcessTouch(Boolean, Boolean) (at
>   Assets/NGUI/Scripts/UI/UICamera.cs:2375) UICamera:ProcessMouse() (at
>   Assets/NGUI/Scripts/UI/UICamera.cs:1830) UICamera:ProcessTouches() (at
>   Assets/NGUI/Scripts/UI/UICamera.cs:1943) UICamera:Update() (at
>   Assets/NGUI/Scripts/UI/UICamera.cs:1631)